# synology NAS, pip issue, python libraries

Tags: python, pip, synology

I recently acquired a NAS and trying to run a python script. Issue is that I cannot run the python script as a normal user (python script.py). Python is only running if I run as a sudo user (e.g., sudo python script.py)
When I run as a normal user, it does not detect the libraries such as pandas. But I do not want to run as a sudo because sudo would required a password.

I think the issue comes from the pip installation.

Do you know what could be the issue?
Greatly appreciate

```
In the terminal, when I run "pip list" as a normal user, it states 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'

`
user@NAS:~$ pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

but when I run as a sudo:

user@NAS:~$ sudo pip list
Password:
Package            Version

---

certifi            2022.6.15
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
idna               3.3
numpy              1.23.2
pandas             1.5.1
pip                22.3.1
pyasn1             0.4.5
pysmb              1.2.2
python-dateutil    2.8.2
pytz               2022.2.1
requests           2.28.1
setuptools         56.0.0
six                1.16.0
thread6            0.2.0
urllib3            1.26.12
wheel              0.38.4

Comment: Excuse me but what Synology and NAS are?

Comment: NAS stands for Network Attached Storage and Synology is a brand that produce them.

Comment: @stoof1982, I think your other user might not have access to python, try to refer this link and see does it help?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435495/giving-access-to-user-installed-python-distribution-to-another-linux-user